# How to get date range start date , to date from one date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have only one date `fromdate` and I want `Fromdate`, `Todate` from data.

Here is my table data:

```
Name            FromDate
---------------------------------------
Spisak, Gregory 2015-11-11 20:30:00.000
Patel, Tejal    2015-11-12 00:50:00.000
George, Legy    2015-11-12 03:52:00.000
Gorny,Alexander 2015-11-12 10:05:00.000
Weiner, Doron   2015-11-12 10:31:00.000
Bajaj, Jimmy    2015-11-12 12:24:00.000
Lee, Richard    2015-11-14 10:00:00.000
Soria, Alfie    2015-11-14 11:15:00.000
Weiner, Moshe   2015-11-16 09:37:00.000
Kariolis,Ioannis2015-11-17 12:15:00.000
Cleary, Tara A  2015-11-17 15:39:00.000
```

I want another `ToDate` column in which I want date of next name's `fromdate`.

For example:

```
Name            FromDate                ToDate
---------------------------------------------------------------
Spisak, Gregory 2015-11-11 20:30:00.000 2015-11-12 00:50:00.000
Patel, Tejal    2015-11-12 00:50:00.000 2015-11-12 03:52:00.000
```

Comment: What's the version of SQL Server you're using? In 2012+ you can use [lead() function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx), which does exactly this.

Comment: Oh thank you.I didnt know anything about lead().

Comment: what do you mean by `next name` ? based on what sequence ?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
select *, todt from yourTable t 
outer apply 
(select top 1 FromDate todt from yourTable 
where FromDate>t.FromDate 
order by FromDate)a
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @TEMP TABLE ( _Date DATE )


INSERT  INTO @TEMP
        ( [_Date] )
VALUES  ( GETDATE()  -- _Date - date
          )

INSERT  INTO @TEMP
        ( [_Date] )
VALUES  ( DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE())  -- _Date - date
          )

INSERT  INTO @TEMP
        ( [_Date] )
VALUES  ( DATEADD(DAY, 2, GETDATE())  -- _Date - date
          )

INSERT  INTO @TEMP
        ( [_Date] )
VALUES  ( DATEADD(DAY, 3, GETDATE())  -- _Date - date
          )

INSERT  INTO @TEMP
        ( [_Date] )
VALUES  ( DATEADD(DAY, 4, GETDATE())  -- _Date - date
          );

WITH    CTE
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY '' ORDER BY [_Date] ) rn
               FROM     @TEMP
             )
    SELECT  CTE.[_Date] AS 'StartDate' ,
            CTE2.[_Date] AS 'EndDate'
    FROM    CTE
            INNER JOIN CTE AS CTE2 ON CTE2.rn = CTE.rn + 1
```